# How can I create this button in CSS3?

Tags: css, button

So far I've got the following html and CSS. I'm stuck on how to achieve the bottom right style with CSS. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Size Chart</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn{
    background: rgba(0,167,253,0.5);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #0093df;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wr08xnu/)

[image: CSS Button]

Comment: That's going to be pretty tricky. Use an image instead, or mask the corner of the button with a pseudo element

Comment: There will be tons of buttons with different widths and colors, so I thought creating it with CSS would be more efficient. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Tricky, but possible.

Comment: A [close approximation](http://jsfiddle.net/7wr08xnu/1/)

Comment: close enough http://jsfiddle.net/3fcooshm/

Comment: Haha, here's my two cents http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/4w915a95/

Comment: this may be helpful http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution using css gradients:
HTML:

```
<span class="btn-outline"><a href="#" class="btn">Size Chart</a></span>
```

CSS:

```
.btn{
    background: rgba(0,167,253,1);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #B2E4FE 5px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #B2E4FE 5px);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #B2E4FE 5px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #B2E4FE 5px);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.btn-outline{
    background: #0093df;
    padding: 1px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px,#0093df 5px);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7vgg0ts/)

Comment: Looks good. Any comments on compatibility? I see your only targeting webkit at the moment.

Comment: Yup! easy enough just to add -moz and -o. I'm simply using chrome at the moment.

Comment: These 2 other prefixes are barely needed now! Fx15- (latest Extended Stable Release of Firefox is Fx 24 ESR) and Opera 11.1-12 (0.05% of marketshare). The one that is very much needed is without prefix though... Source: [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear)

Comment: Is `<br>` useful here?

Comment: nope, left in from when I was trying a few things. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I might found a solution for you, using both `:before` and `:after`:

```
.btn{
    background: rgba(0,167,253,0.5);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #0093df;
    position: relative;
}
.btn:after, .btn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 4px solid white;
    border-color: transparent white white transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
.btn:before {
    border: 5px solid #0093df;
    border-color: transparent #0093df #0093df transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Ld116jv1/).

Please note that it uses a white background, so if your background hasn't a unicolor, it might not function.